# Why does iTerm no longer source ~/.bash_profile, but Mac Terminal does?

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, path

This must be something very simple, but I can't figure it out. Until recently iTerm always properly sourced .bash_profile which has:

```
Sellotape:~ mnewman$ cat .bash_profile
## .bash_profile - Make sure that .bashrc and .profile are read

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi

if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then
    source ~/.profile
fi
```

.profile has this important line from MacPorts:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

This is what Terminal says:

```
Sellotape:~ mnewman$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
Sellotape:~ mnewman$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

And this is what iTerm says:

```
Sellotape:~ mnewman$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
Sellotape:~ mnewman$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

iTerm Settings>Profiles>General>Default has:
command /bin/bash

(I also tried Login Shell, but that didn't work either.)

What have I done to mess up iTerm?

Comment: Provided that you are really using bash (what does `echo $BASH_VERSINFO` say?), note that .bash_profile is not necessarily sourced. Have a look at the bash man-page, section _INVOCATION_, to see under which conditions this file is processed.

Comment: echo $BASH_VERSINFO returns 3. Now that I have set iTerm to run bash as a login shell everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iTerm` does not source your shell startup files.  It is a terminal emulator, not a shell.

The shell you run **inside** `iTerm` sources your shell startup files.

Further, looking at the value of $SHELL is more or less irrelevant.  The contents of $SHELL are what your login shell is, not what shell you currently happen to be in.

Example.  My login shell is `ksh`.  However...

```
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
Version AJM 93u+m/1.1.0-alpha+e9182bd6 2023-09-24   <-- yup, this is ksh
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/ksh                                  <-- and $SHELL agreees
$ bash                                              <-- now launch bash
$ echo $KSH_VERSION
                                                    <-- not in ksh any more
$ echo $SHELL
/usr/local/bin/ksh                                  <-- waitaminit!
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.57(1)-release                                   <-- ah, this *is* bash
$
```

So.

`Bash` reads `.bash_profile` **only for login shells**.  It also doesn't read `.profile` if it can find `.bash_profile`, which I've always thought is more than a little broken.

So `iTerm` is not launching `bash` as a login shell, which means your particular combination of startup files are not being read the way you expect them to be, while `Terminal` is.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise explanation. I learned a lot and fixed the issue. I appreciate your taking the time.