# iterm2 to honor /etc/paths with bash

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm, path, macos

I use Bash as my preferred shell, but the `PATH` values are different in my `iterm2` and my `Terminal` (which honors my `/etc/paths`). How to have iterm2 to honor /etc/paths with the bash shell?

More details:

Both my `iterm2` and my `Terminal` are using Bash as my preferred shell:

[image]

[image]

They're both starting from my default HOME directory, which contains the same files for both of them, but why `Terminal` has paths from my `/etc/paths`, *and*  `/etc/paths.d/`, yet iterm2 only has:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

[image]

**Update**

I tried to use `-i` with item2, but it is still not sourcing `/etc/profile`:

[image]

Actually, it is not sourcing my `~/.bash_profile` file either. Why? Basically, I'm [completely confused with my $PATH, iTerm, ... setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890483/completely-confused-with-my-path-iterm-and-zsh-setup).

Comment: `iTerm` doesn't know or care about your shell startup files.  Only the shell running inside of `iTerm` does.  `Terminal.app` is launching your shell as a login shell, and `iTerm` is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does iTerm no longer source ~/.bash\_profile, but Mac Terminal does?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466800/why-does-iterm-no-longer-source-bash-profile-but-mac-terminal-does)

Comment: Run your bash as login shell, if you want .bash_profile to be processed. This is documented in the bash man-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure iTerm to launch your shell as a login shell.

If you don't start your shell as a login shell—the "Command" option merely starts the program you specify—then your shell won't read configuration relating to a login shell. This includes the path components you're talking about, as well as other login-shell-specific startup.

You can either use your default shell (which is what the "chsh -s" comment is talking about if you try to use Bash):

[image: iTerm preferences, Profiles, General, Command set to "Login Shell".]

Or you can use a custom shell, which will invoke it as a login shell:

[image: iTerm preferences, Profiles, General, Command set to "Custom Shell", "/bin/bash".]

Comment: Ah, I happened to have chosen the _only_ one that is not working as expected, which I did by following some random "helpful" accepted answers I found on the Internet, unfortunately. Your answer is really practical to me. Thanks

Comment: This is incorrect.  You set your shell using the `chsh` tool.   If you want it to be Bash, then use the command `chsh -s /bin/bash`.  What you’re doing is opening a Bash subshell inside a Zsh shell.

Comment: @Allan iTerm2's "Custom Shell" option does not spawn a shell as a subprocess of a shell—rather, it invokes the selected custom shell as a login shell via /usr/bin/login (one of several ways to eventually launch a shell as a login shell.) This is easy to prove: my shell is Zsh, and if I ask iTerm2 to use a Custom Shell of /bin/bash, there is no zsh process running on my system. You're right that you can change your default login shell with chsh, but you don't need to.

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  A login shell is created when you initially login to macOS.  You can prove this by issuing the command, in any shell, `sudo ps -A | grep -i tty`.   Note your login shell.  Your login shell will always be the shell that is configured with `chsh`, not iTerm's "custom shell."  No matter what, you're opening a subshell.

Comment: @Allan I'm sorry, but you're arguing from a place of limited information. Please do some reading up, for example, on what "bash --login" does—since this is one way bash may be launched as a login shell that has nothing to do with chsh. You may also find the iTerm documentation handy—see "Command" on this page: https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-profiles-general.html

Comment: Good luck, Mattie.